# Mutability of request in pattern Chain of Responsibility

Tags: design-patterns

I try to realise core features of pattern Chain of Responsibility.
One of questions is about mutability of request that client generates.
Can request be mutable when it is passing through chain of handlers ?

I think the patterns are abstractions allowing to help in architecturing, so it's up to developer to decide make the request mutable or not.

But I want to know about mutability as a feature of this pattern - does it make sence or not?

I've not found answer in the oficial books about patterns. May be this means that mutability doesn't matters?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it doesn't matter.

In the case of a logging COR, then you'd avoid modifications on the request. But let's say you have an event that go trough the chain and that need to be handled by one of the part of the COR. In this case you'd modify the event, to indicate that it was handled.